# Why do i get antivirus alert when use smtp & GetAsyncKeyState

Tags: c#, winforms

I got antivirus alert tr\gen8 spy when I build

here is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace reading
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys vKey);

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtpClient;
    }

}
 }
```

Any suggestion?

And thanks for help

Comment: Maybe you have the virus.  If you are sure you do not, AV scanners turn up false positives all the time.  Exclude your exe from the scanner.  If you need help doing that you can ask over at SuperUser.

Comment: I don't have virus I'am sure the alert appear just when I build I try to create new project and it's give me the same result , but when I remove ( System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient ) or ( GetAsyncKeyState) It's build succuffly , If any one help me to compile the same code . Thanks for help

Comment: Because scanning for system-wide keypress is how virus that steal information works.